# Using old telecom router as AP behind wireless bridge

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point, bridge

I'm trying to extend my wireless network in my home by using an old router from my telecom provider as an AP. (Specifically, a b-box3 by Proximus in Belgium). The router is running annoying proprietary software though which shields off a lot of the settings.

I'm using a Netgear WNCE4004 to receive the wifi signal from my new router, and get decent speeds on the ethernet outputs of the Netgear (30-40 Mbit down). However, I'm getting mixed results when trying to get the old router to function as an AP.

Am I correct in thinking that it should work to assign a fixed IP address to the old router, disable the DHCP server on it, and connect it to the Netgear bridge?

Or should I be doing something else/am I missing something?

Here is the diagram:

[image]

Comment: Can you draw some kind of diagram of all those devices sending and receiving Ethernet and Wi-Fi signals?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/C4RYn